# VSql client hangs after restore

Tags: vertica, vsql

After restoring a database from a backup using vbr utility, when I start the database, queries fail to execute. The vertica log shows the query but it is not executed. Moreover, I cannot exit vsql or cancel the command and the cluster no longer accepts any queries. 
I am not sure what went wrong since the restore completed successfully. 
Any ideas how this can be fixed ?

log entries:

> 2017-09-11 08:50:24.681 Init Session:0x7ff780011dc0 [Session]  [Query] TX:0(******.-1964:0x19cc2) select 1;
>   2017-09-11 08:53:25.001 TM Mergeout(01):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e02 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e02 'Mergeout: Tuple Mover'
>   2017-09-11 08:53:27.257 TM Mergeout(01):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e02 [TM]  Tuple Mover: nothing to merge out
>   2017-09-11 08:53:27.439 TM Mergeout(01):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e02 [TM]  Tuple Mover: no DV to merge out
>   2017-09-11 08:53:27.439 TM Mergeout(01):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e02 [Txn]  Rollback Txn: a0000000000e02 'Mergeout: Tuple Mover'
>   2017-09-11 08:53:27.517 TM Mergeout(01):0x7ff77807c620 [Util]  Task 'TM Mergeout(01)' enabled
>   2017-09-11 08:53:50.001 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e03 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e03 'Mergeout: Tuple Mover'
>   2017-09-11 08:53:52.056 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e03 [TM]  Tuple Mover: nothing to merge out
>   2017-09-11 08:53:52.219 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e03 [TM]  Tuple Mover: no DV to merge out
>   2017-09-11 08:53:52.219 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e03 [Txn]  Rollback Txn: a0000000000e03 'Mergeout: Tuple Mover'
>   2017-09-11 08:53:52.286 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e04 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e04 'collectMoveStorageJobs'
>   2017-09-11 08:53:52.467 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e04 [Txn]  Rollback Txn: a0000000000e04 'collectMoveStorageJobs'
>   2017-09-11 08:53:52.472 TM Mergeout(00):0x7ff77807c620 [Util]  Task 'TM Mergeout(00)' enabled
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.008 TM Moveout:0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e05 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e05 'Moveout: Tuple Mover'
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.008 TM Moveout:0x7ff77807c620-a0000000000e05 [Txn]  Rollback Txn: a0000000000e05 'Moveout: Tuple Mover'
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.009 TM Moveout:0x7ff77807c620 [Util]  Task 'TM Moveout' enabled
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.013 LGELaggingCheck:0x7ff778012ae0-a0000000000e06 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e06 'Recovery: Get last good epoch'
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.104 LGELaggingCheck:0x7ff778012ae0-a0000000000e06 [Txn]  Starting Commit: Txn: a0000000000e06 'Recovery: Get last good epoch'
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.106 LGELaggingCheck:0x7ff778012ae0 [Txn]  Commit Complete: Txn: a0000000000e06 at epoch 0x245ec
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.106 LGELaggingCheck:0x7ff778012ae0-a0000000000e07 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e07 'Check LGE'
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.106 LGELaggingCheck:0x7ff778012ae0-a0000000000e07 [Txn]  Rollback Txn: a0000000000e07 'Check LGE'
>   2017-09-11 08:54:11.107 LGELaggingCheck:0x7ff778012ae0 [Util]  Task 'LGELaggingCheck' enabled
>   2017-09-11 08:55:37.352 Init Session:0x7ff780011720  @v_mn_node0001: 00000/2705: Connection received: host=********* port=**** (connCnt 6)
>   2017-09-11 08:55:37.352 Init Session:0x7ff780011720  @v_mn_node0001: 00000/4540: Received SSL negotiation startup packet
>   2017-09-11 08:55:37.352 Init Session:0x7ff780011720  @v_mn_node0001: 00000/4691: Sending SSL negotiation response 'N'
>   2017-09-11 08:55:37.353 Init Session:0x7ff780011720  @v_mn_node0001: 00000/4686: Authentication - sendAuthRequest: user=**** database=**** host=******** authType=3
>   2017-09-11 08:55:37.353 Init Session:0x7ff780011720-a0000000000e08 [Txn]  Begin Txn: a0000000000e08 'check_login_history'
>   2017-09-11 08:55:37.353 Init Session:0x7ff780011720-a0000000000e08 [Txn]  Rollback Txn: a0000000000e08 'check_login_history'

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !